# NoReverseMatch at / error in django after url template tag usage

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I am having this error after using the template `{% url %}` tag,

```
NoReverseMatch at /index/

Reverse for 'index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

this happened when I changed `href="index"` to `href="{% url 'index' %}"`.

my url is

```
url(r'^index/$', views.index, name='index'),
```

I tried to remove `$` but still the same error?

Comment: You're probably missing the url namespace

Comment: my urls.py is namespaced as in app_name = 'actual app name'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `app_name` you provided will be used as the namespace for the urls. You should include that in the tag like so:

```
href="{% url 'actual_app_name:index' %}"
```

See [URL namespaces and included URLconfs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs).